# How do I create primefaces data table in which the headers and sub headers are based on parent and n children

Tags: jsf, primefaces

[image]
I have to create a primefaces data table in which the headers and sub headers are based on parent and n children. A header column can have sub headers which are children of the parent header. Based on number of children row span and column span has to be set. But a parent can have n number of children. Dynamically the code has to set the UI table based on parent and child.

Here like INFO header has two children S.NO and CODE. Likewise if CODE has any other children like MAIN CODE AND SUB CODE that should dynamically occur under CODE with respect to the object which has parentName.

Comment: Doesn't this duplicate https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64607868/how-to-construct-primefaces-datatable-header-for-n-levelmore-than-3-level-chil?

Comment: @JasperdeVries for static data, the solution works. But when the number of children is dynamic for example might be four or might be two dynamically. Then at that time, the solution isn't available.

Comment: Did you try JSTL (`<c:if test="...">row</c:if>`) and EL?

Comment: What about create subtable and decorate it as header?